# Bootsrap pagination, how to show set number of page links

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

The pagination shows 4 links and then an ellipse (...). I have plenty of width, I need to show 10 pagination links. This is what I have:

```
    <b-pagination-nav
        prev-text="Prev"
        next-text="Next"
        base-url="/"
        v-model="thePage"
        :link-gen="linkGen"
        :number-of-pages="10"
        :per-page="1"></b-pagination-nav>
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

How do I get it to show more page links ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the prop "limit"

```
:limit="10"
```

From bootstrap-vue documentation:

Limiting the number of displayed buttons
To restrict the number of page buttons (including the ellipsis, but excluding the first, prev, next, and last buttons) shown, use the limit prop to specify the desired number of page buttons (including the ellipsis, if shown). The default limit is 5. The minimum supported value is 3. When limit is set to 3, no ellipsis indicators will be shown for practical purposes.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination-nav#limiting-the-number-of-displayed-buttons